# Is there a way to write a non 8bit aligned data to a binary file in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I need to write data to a binary file, while all the data is aligned to be in Bytes, it's made of several fragments which are not alighted to Bytes:

The total size of the data is 96 bits comprised of:

- RGB color: 3*8 bit numbers (24bit),
- 1st property value: 7bit number
- 2nd property value: 7bit number
- number of objects: 26bit number
- memory offsert: 32bit number.

totaling to 96bit or 12B

The reason that the data is split this way is that each number has significance and it's easier to create the data by putting the numbers separately in their correct order. I'm using [`fwrite`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fwrite.html) for this, but the function only allows to write numbers in sizes of Bytes. I found a way around it by using a "hack":

```
num=red;
num=num*2^8+green;
num=num*2^8+blue;
num=num*2^7+first_prop_val;
num=num*2^7+second_prop_val;
num=num*2^26+number_of_objects;
fwrite(fid, num,'uint64');
fwrite(fid, memory_offset,'uint32');
```

This works because all the numbers are positive, but it's ugly. Is there a less "hacky" way to accomplish what I need?

---

<sup>*-the property numbers are the size of 7 because they can get values from 0 to 100, and giving them an extra bit just to align the data would mean that I can have less objects as they all need to be counted</sup>

Comment: Memory storage and file I/O is inherently byte-aligned, and there will always be a "hack" to shift non-aligned to aligned.  Yours isn't bad as it is.  Look into `bitshift` and `bitor` for a version not subject to double-precision math, but it won't be shorter than your version.

Answer (score 0):

For a signed 32bit integer, you can get the binary representation using:

```
bi=dec2bin(typecast(int32(-23),'uint32'))=='1'
```

Signed: You heading n bits, if they are equal to the n+1th bit

```
bw=7
assert all(bi(1:end-bw+1))|all(~bi(1:end-bw+1))
bi=bi(end-bw+1:end)
```

For a unsigned one, use:

```
bi=dec2bin(uint32(23))=='1'
```

Unsigned: You can remove heading zeros.

```
assert(all(~bi(1:end-bw)))
bi=bi(end-bw+1:end)
```

Put this into a function, convert all integers, concatenate to one binary array, cut in 32bit parts and write using uint32-format.

Comment: You are suggesting just another hack, and frankly a more complected and less readable one.

Comment: There might be a better solution using the fixed point designer, but without I don't know a better solution. Cutting / Padding heading bits this way isn't a hack, it's the normal way to change the bit width.